# Find duplicate entries in a column in PostgreSQL graphql hasura?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

How do i find the Duplicate Values in One Column in **PostgreSQL GraphQL Hasura**. i know there is a **Groupby** in SQL but do i do in this case?

Comment: Please provide [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a view and query it like a normal table;

let us assume there's a **people** table with a **first_name** column. To find duplicates

```
create or replace view duplicate_first_names as select p.first_name,
count(p.first_name) from people p group by(p.first_name) having
count(p.first_name) > 1
```

or if you want to return the entire row of the duplicate column, you can add a sub-query:

```
create or replace view duplicate_people_first_names as select * from
people p where (select count(*) from people ppl where ppl.first_name =
p.first_name) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group By is not currently exposed by default in the generated GraphQL API. You can extend the API using [Postgres Views](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/schema/views.html) or [Functions](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/schema/custom-functions.html) to achieve the functionality you are looking for

Comment: can you pls provide me the related resource ?